# Magento ERP Connect

Tags: magento, integration, odoo, magento-1.4

I'm using **magentoerpconnect_generic** in my OpenERP with version 5.0.1.0 integrate with Magento.
I can export the Catalog normally but when I change the Product Name for example, and I export it again, the product name doesn't update in my Magento.
Anyone know the solution?

Comment: I try to setup both OpenLabs and SnelDev Magento-OpenERP bridge, but still none of them works for me at all.